# Feeding javascript xml file when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

I'm looking to load a lot of values out of a xml file when a html page loads. The xml file is static, and never changes. It will be hosted in the same directory as the html page. The xml file will be used to populate a few select boxes in the html. I figured I could populate the select boxes using javascript. However, I'm wondering how I can pass the contents of the xml file to javascript. Is ajax the only solution? Or is there a way to feed javascript the xml file when the page loads.

Thank you!

Comment: in a word: YES. That's what the "X" in "AJAX" stands for.

Answer (score 0):

If it is static and truly never changes, consider converting it to JSON and embedding it straight into your JavaScript. More efficient as there is one less HTTP request. If size of data is an issue, then AJAX may be your only solution